# React install issue , node_modules is not getting generated

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

In React npm install is not creating node_modules even though npm install is being run completely and at last line it will throw below error. like below and there won't be any node_modules in the project.

npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.2: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.11: please switch to a stable version
***npm ERR! cb() never called!***

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://npm.community

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm and node versions are like below.
**node -v
v14.15.1
npm -v
6.14.8**

Answer (score 0):

Warning with `deprecated fsevents` can be probably fixed by updating `fsevents` library but you have to check if it will solve issue with `node_modules`